# Short story about trading shares of people as financial instruments

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

A few years ago I read an excellent short story that I've been looking for ever since. Here's what I can remember: In this story's world it was common for people to sell shares of themselves (or shares of their future income) on the financial markets, like how companies sell shares of stock. The protagonist is a trader who specializes in short-selling shares of people. One day the protagonist takes out a massive short position against another person and then leaks to the press that person's mental health records.

Does anyone know where this short story might be?

Comment: I can't speak to short stories but Robert Shiller, Yale professor and Nobel Laureate in Economics, wrote a 2009 book titled *The New Financial Order:
Risk in the 21st Century* in which he proposed human markets where someone's future income earning potential was traded for an investment today. The example he used was a South African music student having difficulty financing her tuition. She resorts to a yet to be created financial entity like a commodities futures market and receives a loan covering tuition. This is like a swap option where future risk is mitigated based on present value.